# Load javascript state from rendered elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Just wanted to know is there any javascript framework or lib that could load part of initial state from existing DOM elements.

Could reactjs or vuejs do things like this?

So to be perfectly clear i want to render page on server and mark some elements to be part of the model. The idea is to be able to render html with some important data so search engines could get it without js. Regular use would have exactly the same page but once js kicks in, I want it to get data from marked fields and add to current state.

i.e.

```
<h1 x-marker="pageTitle">Page Title</h1>
<h2>{{ subtitle }}</h2>


var state = {
    subtitle: 'This is subtitle',
}
```

search engine sees this:

```
<h1>Page Title</h1>
<h2>{{subtitle}}</h2>
```

regular user sees this:

```
<h1>Page Title</h1>
<h2>This is subtitle</h2>
```

BUT state should be

```
var state = {
    pageTitle: 'Page Title',
    subtitle: 'This is subtitle',
}
```

So I want it to initially pull data from x-marker and after that maintain state of that element.

I could implement this kind of thing myself, just wanted to check does something like this already exists.

Comment: React + redux seems to be what you want, a view library and a state manager

Comment: Yeah, React is capable of that.

Comment: How would you pull data from rendered element, in my example h1, using react/redux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the [crazy nastyass honeybadger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4r7wHMg5Yjg), vue doesn't care. You can do whatever you like (read the dom, substitute), so long as you do it before you instantiate the vue.

[This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bbsimonbb/8ysn00jn/) shows your scenario working fine. The idea strikes me as a little louche, and certainly server-side rendering is the preferred way of dealing with this. Vue also has [server-side rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html), but you could be forgiven for taking fright. If this gets you out of a hole, go for it. As they say, be good, and if you can't be good, be careful :-)

**HTML**

```
<div id="crazyNastyass">
  <h1 id="pageTitle">Page Title</h1>
  <h2>{{state.subtitle}}</h2>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var state = {
    pageTitle:null,
    subtitle: 'This is subtitle'
}

var titleNode = document.getElementById('pageTitle');
state.pageTitle = titleNode.innerHTML;
titleNode.innerHTML = '{{state.pageTitle}}'

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#crazyNastyass',
  data: {state:state}
})
```

Comment: This is actually manual way to do this but I will accept it as an answer. I was thinking is this possible without manual part where you get content of the field and then update state. I was hoping this is done as part of some lib or framework.

Comment: Yup. I actually think you're better off having it manual. Your logic for harvesting the state is concise, and totally separate from the action of the framework. You're losing the ability to see the dynamic bits in your markup, but you'll keep all the substitions together in one place, so they should be easy to keep track of. Don't try doing this with React :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise strongly against the method you proposed and look into how to do server side rendering for your React apps.

There's something about server rendering in the React docs:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring

Next.js is a good framework to help you with this
https://github.com/zeit/next.js

Comment: Why do you think this is bad solution? Can you add some thoughts?